# Trouble cloning a git repository from an EC2 instance

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to put a bare git repository on a ubuntu server running on Amazon EC2.  The difficulty I'm having is getting git to clone the repository from my local pc.

When I try:

```
git clone git@ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/opt/git/project.git
```

I get:

```
Cloning into project...
Unable to open connection:
Host does not existfatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Yet I don't have any difficulty ssh'ing into the same server.  For example the following works fine:

```
ssh git@ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

My thinking was that if this is working, then I have my keys set up appropriately on the client, and on the server.  Therefore the git clone command should work as well.

But no.

I've researched and tried a number of variations, but I just have hunch I'm missing something brain dead simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check to make sure git is doing what you think it is doing, and then try the exact command git is using to contact the remote server.

Run `GIT_TRACE=1 git clone git@ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/opt/git/project.git`

Git will tell you what command it is running, ex

```
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''/opt/git/project.git'\'''
```

You can then try to run that command yourself to eliminate git from the picture:

```
ssh git@ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com git-upload-pack '/opt/git/project.git'
```

While it seems unlikely given your reported error message, stracing the command can also provide hints:

```
strace -o/tmp/tr -s128 -f ssh git@ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com git-upload-pack '/opt/git/project.git'
```

Report back the debugging information revealed above if there are still problems.

Comment: Thanks for the debug help.  It gave me a few ideas.  I can't explain why, but the upgrading my version of msysgit 1.7.3.1 preview to 1.7.4 preview seemed to solve the problem.  I was hoping for something clearer than that, but there you have it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.  I was having a similar problem trying to clone from an external GIT source to an EC2 host.  I got things working using some of the above.

It had been failing with:

```
[ec2-user@*.*.*. mediagoblin]$ sudo git clone git://gitorious.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin.git
Cloning into mediagoblin...
gitorious.org[0: 87.238.52.168]: errno=Connection timed out
gitorious.org[0: 2a02:c0:1014::1]: errno=Network is unreachable
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Network is unreachable)
```

I then tried replacing `git://` with `ssh://` and got:

```
sudo git clone ssh://gitorious.org/mediagoblin/mediagoblin.git
Cloning into mediagoblin...
The authenticity of host 'gitorious.org (87.238.52.168)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is *:*:*:*:*:**:.  
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitorious.org,87.238.52.168' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I then ran the original `git://` request and it worked.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The git account may not have read / write access to that repository/branch.

Comment: In process of trying your suggestion.  But do you need more than read access for a clone?

Answer (score 0):

Git uses port 9418. Is this open on your instance?

Comment: Really?  I thought that git worked over the ssh protocol (port 22), which is what I was attempting to do.  I have ports 80 and 22 open.  I'm not using a git server (gitosis?).

Comment: Only git protocol / git daemon is 9418

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ssh:// to the remote address. I have never had good luck getting git to work consistently without it.

`git clone ssh://git@ec2-blah.compute-1.amazonaws.com/opt/git/project.git`